# How can we show next or previous image as we swipe right or left in react native?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation

Well here i have a react native component with the implementation of geasture controls. 100% working code with no error. But now i want to achieve the functionality as we swipe right its shows previous image or if it swipes left it shows next images. as it looks the current image going back and new image coming. I have tried to figure this out but unable to do that.

here is code .

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { FlatList, Image, Modal, Text, View ,StyleSheet,Dimensions, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import { GestureHandlerRootView, PanGestureHandler, } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Animated ,{useAnimatedStyle,useAnimatedGestureHandler, useSharedValue, withTiming,Easing} from 'react-native-reanimated';
  
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
const GridListing = () => {
  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(null);
  const x = useSharedValue(0);


  

  const handleImagePress = (index) => {
    setSelectedImage(index);
  };

  const closeImagePreview = () => {
    setSelectedImage(null);
  }

  const nextImage = () => {
    const currentIndex = arrayOfObjects.findIndex((obj) => obj.id === selectedImage.id);
    if (currentIndex === arrayOfObjects.length - 1) {
      closeImagePreview();
    } else {
      setSelectedImage(arrayOfObjects[currentIndex + 1]);
    }
  }
  
  const previousImage = () => {
    const currentIndex = arrayOfObjects.findIndex((obj) => obj.id === selectedImage.id);
    if (currentIndex === 0) {
      closeImagePreview();
    } else {
      setSelectedImage(arrayOfObjects[currentIndex - 1]);
    }
  }

  const animationContainerStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
    transform:  [{ translateX: withTiming(x.value,{
      duration:100,
      easing:Easing.linear,
    }) }]
  }));

  const handleSwipe = useAnimatedGestureHandler({
    onActive: (event) => {
      if (Math.abs(event.translationX) > Math.abs(event.translationY)) {
        // Horizontal swipe
        if (event.translationX > 0) {
          console.log('Swiping right');
          x.value = event.translationX

        } else {
          console.log('Swiping left',event.translationX);
          x.value = event.translationX
      
        }
      } else {
        // Vertical swipe
        if (event.translationY > 0) {
          console.log('Swiping down');
        } else {
          console.log('Swiping up');
        }
      }
    },
    onEnd:()=>{
      if (x.value>width/2) {
        x.value = withTiming(width,{easing:Easing.linear}) 
        console.log("hey")
        const currentIndex = arrayOfObjects.findIndex(obj => obj.id === selectedImage?.id);
        console.log("currentIndex ",currentIndex)
        
      
        // setSelectedImage(arrayOfObjects[(currentIndex + 1) % arrayOfObjects.length]);
      }else if (x.value < -width / 2) {
        x.value = withTiming(-width,{easing:Easing.linear}) 
        console.log("ho")
      }else{
        x.value=withTiming(0,{easing:Easing.linear}) 
        console.log("oo")
      }
    }
  })

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={arrayOfObjects}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.itemContainer} onPress={() => handleImagePress(item)}>
            <Image style={styles.thumbnail} source={{ uri: item.imageUrl }} />
             </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
        numColumns={3}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
      />
      <Modal
        transparent
        visible={selectedImage !== null}
        onRequestClose={() => setSelectedImage(null)}
        style={styles.modalContainer}
      >
        <GestureHandlerRootView style={{flex:1}}> 
          <PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={handleSwipe}>
            <Animated.View style={[styles.modalContainer,animationContainerStyle]} >
          
            <Image
                source={{ uri: selectedImage?.imageUrl }}
                style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
                resizeMode="contain"
              />
            </Animated.View>


          </PanGestureHandler>
      </GestureHandlerRootView>
          {/* <PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={handleSwipe}>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'pink' ,flexDirection:"row",}}>
              <Animated.View style={{backgroundColor:"yellow",width:100,height:100}} />
              
            </View>
          </PanGestureHandler> */}
      </Modal>
    </View>
  );
  };
```

Comment: what have u done so far, does swipe work but shows nothing or what ?

Comment: and if u can create a snack for that, it would be very helpfull